# Excel clipping data off long number before I can format it correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get around Excel's pesky automatic number formatting on a certain document. I know how to format it so it's not an issue (custom with a format of "0"), however by the time I load it, it's already formatted as scientific notation and clipped information off the second half of the number.

Is there perhaps a VBA script that would affect cell formatting before I load the document?

Comment: use the import wizard and mark that column as text before importing.

Comment: I ended up using LibreOffice as there's an option to pick column formatting before you import, but it is a major inconvenience in the first place. If there's a excel-based solution, that would be good to know.    EDIT>> Just read your comment craner, thanks much!